# trouble escaping a json string in an erb template

Tags: json, escaping, string-formatting, puppet, erb

I'm using json+puppet+erb to create a config file. I need the logformat to look like this:

```
LogFormat "%h %l \"%{foobar}i\" \"%{moarfoobar}i\"" combined
```

I can't get the \"%{foobar}i\"" and  \"%{moarfoobar}i\"" outputs right. I believe puppet is trying to parse that part of the string, when I need it to just dump. Here's some escaping that I've tried, and the output:

```
no-escaping
json:   "LogFormat": "\"%h %l \\\"%{foobar}i\\\" \\\"%{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined",
output: logformat "%h %l \"i\" \"i\"" combined

single-escape
json:    "LogFormat": "\"%h %l \\\"%\{foobar}i\\\" \\\"\%{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined",
output: logformat "%h %l \"i\" \"i\"" combined

double-escape
json:   "LogFormat": "\"%h %l \\\"\\%{foobar}i\\\" \\\"%\\{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined",
output: LogFormat "%h %l \"\i\" \"%\{moarfoobar}i\"" combined
```

I've tried escaping both the percent and the curley-bracket with no luck. The best I can do so far is the double-escape, but it adds the extra backslash.

Here is my erb:

```
<% @config.sort_by {|k, v|}.each do |key,value|-%>
<%= "#{key}\t\t #{value}" %>
<% end -%>
```

Any ideas? Let me know if more info is needed

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON from here. Is that data that you feed into Hiera?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a snippet of the json. It's basically:

    {
      "config": {
        "apache": {
          "LogFormat": "\"%h %l \\\"%{foobar}i\\\" \\\"%{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined",
          "otherconfig": "values_here"
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Is it loaded through Hiera though? Because Hiera **will** try and expand the `%{...}` expressions.

Comment: Is that where the problem is? is there a clean way to escape hiera then?

Answer (score 1):

Just-released Hiera 2.0.0 supposedly has a solution for escaping interpolation tokens.  If I understand correctly, you would spell your value like this:

```
"\"%h %l \\\"%{foobar}i\\\" \\\"%{literal('%')}{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined"
```

If you cannot upgrade to 2.0.0 or do not want to do, then you could perform a similar trick with earlier Hiera by setting a top-scope variable in your site manifest:

```
$percent = '%'
```

and referencing that in your hiera data:

```
"\"%h %l \\\"%{foobar}i\\\" \\\"%{::precent}{moarfoobar}i\\\"\" combined"
```

of course, the latter works only when Hiera is invoked by Puppet; the former should work (in Hiera 2) regardless of how Hiera is invoked.